# How to put results in single "table"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Every time I run this query

```
Declare @name varchar(100)
Declare @sqlstatement nvarchar(4000)
--move declare cursor into sql to be executed
Declare users_cursor CURSOR FOR Select name from sys.databases where 
database_id > 4
declare @bdname varchar(100)
declare @test varchar(100)
set @test ='myserver'
--declare  @listagem table(ServerName  varchar(100),DatabaseName  
varchar(100), UserName  varchar(100), [UserRole]  varchar(100))


OPEN users_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM users_cursor
INTO @name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
print 'Database ' + @name

set @bdname = @name 
set @sqlstatement = N'use ' + @name +' '+char(13)+N' select '''+ @test +''', ''' + @bdname +''',
convert(char(30),dp2.name), convert(char(20),dp.name)  
FROM sys.database_principals dp
INNER JOIN sys.database_role_members drm ON dp.principal_id = 
drm.role_principal_id
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals dp2 ON drm.member_principal_id = 
dp2.principal_id
WHERE dp2.principal_id > 4 AND dp2.type <>'+'''R'''


exec sp_executesql @sqlstatement

FETCH NEXT FROM users_cursor -- have to fetch again within loop
INTO @name
END
CLOSE users_cursor
DEALLOCATE users_cursor
END
```

The result is presented as if like it was several tables in the output window.

Is there a way that I can run this having the output as a single "table"?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the current output you have, and describe better what you want?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: Since you're getting results from more than 1 database, each result is being displayed each time the query runs in the cursor. You'd have to write the results to @@tempTable for each query and then select * from @@temptable after the cursor; not in the cursor.  The problem is being caused by multiple query executions for each name in the users_cursor; 2 apparently.

Comment: Use sys.databases and SELECT @sqlStatement += to dynamically build a query to union all the different databases. No need for a temp table.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @sqlstatement NVARCHAR(4000);
--move declare cursor into sql to be executed
DECLARE users_cursor CURSOR
FOR SELECT name
    FROM sys.databases
    WHERE database_id > 4;
DECLARE @bdname VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(100);
SET @test = 'myserver';
DECLARE @listagem TABLE
(ServerName   VARCHAR(100),
 DatabaseName VARCHAR(100),
 UserName     VARCHAR(100),
 [UserRole]   VARCHAR(100)
);
OPEN users_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM users_cursor INTO @name;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Database '+@name;
        SET @bdname = @name;
        SET @sqlstatement = N'use '+@name+' '+CHAR(13)+N' select '''+@test+''', '''+@bdname+''',
convert(char(30),dp2.name), convert(char(20),dp.name)  
FROM sys.database_principals dp
INNER JOIN sys.database_role_members drm ON dp.principal_id = 
drm.role_principal_id
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals dp2 ON drm.member_principal_id = 
dp2.principal_id
WHERE dp2.principal_id > 4 AND dp2.type <>'+'''R''';
        INSERT INTO @listagem
        EXEC sp_executesql
             @sqlstatement; 
        FETCH NEXT FROM users_cursor -- have to fetch again within loop
        INTO @name;
    END;
CLOSE users_cursor;
DEALLOCATE users_cursor;
SELECT *
FROM @listagem;
```

You are actually very close to the solution.

use the table you are declaring:

```
DECLARE @listagem TABLE
    (ServerName   VARCHAR(100),
     DatabaseName VARCHAR(100),
     UserName     VARCHAR(100),
     [UserRole]   VARCHAR(100)
    );
```

and simply insert the result returened from each itteration of the loop into the table like so:

```
INSERT INTO @listagem
    EXEC sp_executesql
         @sqlstatement;
```

and then simply select from the table outside of the cursor:

```
SELECT *
FROM @listagem;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for SQL Server 2012 and later. If you need SQL Server 2008 then I'll have to edit to not use CONCAT() function unless you can figure out the difference. This will return all Database Principals and their accompanying Database Roles for all your Databases. Keep in mind that any permission not at a database level (sysadmin) won't show up in this query.

```
DECLARE @sqlStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @sqlStatement +=
CONCAT
(
        'SELECT ''',[name],'''
        ,CONVERT(CHAR(30),DP.[name]) AS DatabasePrincipal
        ,CONVERT(CHAR(20),DR.[name]) AS DatabaseRole
    FROM [',[name],'].sys.database_principals AS DP
        LEFT JOIN [',[name],'].sys.database_role_members AS DRM
            ON DP.principal_id = DRM.member_principal_id
        LEFT JOIN [',[name],'].sys.database_principals AS DR
            ON DRM.role_principal_id = DR.principal_id
    WHERE DR.[name] IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    '
)
FROM sys.databases
;

SET @sqlStatement = LEFT(@sqlStatement,LEN(@sqlStatement)-12);

EXEC sp_executeSQL @sqlStatement;
```